# create a new pattern for Activity ID in Primavera P6

Tags: project-planning, primavera

I am working with Primavera P6.
I have a new project with a defined WBS. I want for each level of the WBS, when I create a new activity, have a default Activity ID previously defined, for example:

WBS:

PROJECT

Engineering

Mechanical

Civil

Piping

...

Procurement

Manufacturing

...

Construction

Area 1

Area 2

...

And for each of these WBS groups, when I create a new activity on it, I dont want the typical A00000 Activity ID, instead I want for example PR1ENME001 (**PR**oject**1**, **EN**gineering activity, **ME**chanical and is the **001** activity)

Comment: You will need to number your activities manually. You can do that with the API if you call the setId(...) method in the Activity. You might need to retrieve the whole set of activities for a given project and parse the IDs in order to determine the next value, but it is doable if you do that. I don't see any other way of reliable placing the ID of your activities if you don't retrieve the whole set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's the trick.

First create at least 1 activity with your desired Activity ID pattern in each WBS area. Then, highlight that activity and create a new one. It should copy the pattern to the new activity and increment the IDs number automatically.

But there is a setting for this.

On the **Projects window**, find your project, highlight it, and find the Defaults tab in the bottom half of the screen. Make sure the option "**Increment Activity ID based on selected Activity**" is checked **on**.

If you want to edit existing IDs to match your pattern, then you can either use Edit->Renumber Activity IDs, or you can use a Global Change - here's how https://www.planacademy.com/tutorials/edit-activity-ids-primavera-p6-via-global-change/